# Using DISTINCT with UNION/UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've stumbled across a slow-performing section of code that looks alot like this.

```
SELECT
  res.[X],
  res.[Y],
  SUM(res.[Z]) -- This is SUM so I have to remove duplicates
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT a.[X], a.[Y], b.[Z] FROM [A] a JOIN [B] b ON a.[ID] = b.[ID]
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT a.[X], a.[Y], c.[Z] FROM [A] a JOIN [C] c ON a.[ID] = c.[ID]
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT a.[X], a.[Y], d.[Z] FROM [A] a JOIN [D] d ON a.[ID] = d.[ID]
  UNION ALL -- This set won't have duplicates, hence the UNION ALL in this case
  SELECT a.[X], a.[Y], n.[Z] FROM [A] a JOIN [N] n ON a.[ID] = n.[ID]
) res
GROUP BY res.[X], res.[Y]
```

The joins are alot more complex and there are 12 of these UNION/UNION ALLs, but you get the picture. Each result set usually contains between 1 and 15 million rows.

I'm wondering how anyone else would write this query. I read a couple other threads that warn against:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [A]
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM [B]
```

because the DISTINCT is called three times (in this small example). So I gave that a shot and removed the DISTINCT. The result was actually alot slower. I don't understand how removing extra filtering would cause the query to run slower.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm digging into the query plan, but it's much too large to post so I'm just looking for suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me more details about your tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using row number and select out the min value for each X,Y and Z

```
select 
    MIN(myfilter),
    X,
    Y,
    Z
SELECT 
    a.[X], 
    a.[Y], 
    b.[Z] 
RowNumber() over (order by A.X, a.Y, b.Z) as MyFilter

    FROM [A] a JOIN [B] b ON a.[ID] = b.[ID]
)
group by x,y,z
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What happens to my SUM?

Comment: That should select out duplicate data; your sum would need to wrap around the select